# Proper terminology for a pair of magmas

Tags: abstract-algebra, type-theory

Given two magmas, call them $f$ and $g$ over the same set $a$, what do I call a tuple $h$ of them?  With extra properties we call them such names as fields and rings. I am just looking for the generic term for a pair of magmas.

Haskell notation:

--Cayley table for magma $f$

f :: a -> a -> a

--Cayley table for magma $g$

g :: a -> a -> a

-- What do you call this tuple of magmas?

h :: (f,g)

Comment: A «pair of magmas»? Why do you expect it to have a name?

Comment: This is just a set with two binary operations.